# How to automatically encode Unicode Strings when externalizing in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, localization, internationalization

I want to prepare resource bundle with localized strings. The problem is that java properties files don't support unicode. Therefore, I need to keep strings like \u0412\u044B... in my properties file. Is there a way to translate strings into such format automatically using Intellij IDEA?

[image]

I tried to use some embedded editor but it doesn't covert strings to \u0412\u044B... representation.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Editor/File Encodings* and check *Transparent native-to-ascii conversion*.

With that option enabled any Unicode characters in your properties files will get automatically converted to corresponding escape sequences.